# Creating an unbounded number of objects in Python 2.7.3

Tags: python, class, variable-assignment, infinite, continuous

I have started to make an artificial life simulator in Python 2.7.3 but I am unable to create classes at runtime, continuously. I know that I can do this in C++ by storing the class in a list. Does anyone know how to do this? I mean something like this:

```
x = 1
name = list()
name[x] = myClass()
x+=1
name[x] = myClass()
```

And so on, although I will be using a loop for this.

Comment: Your wording has severely confused my metaprogramming-damaged brain. Some of my code is actually creating classes at runtime. But I assume you meant instantiating classes, AKA creating objects?

Comment: Yes. I mean creating objects at runtime. I shall add that bit of information to the question.

Comment: Well, what have you tried? Surely you have some Python tutorial or other resources -- how are they not helping you?

Comment: I have looked around (I started looking half a year ago) but either I do not know the correct wording to use when searching (highly possible) or there is no information for this on the first few pages of Google search results. I have read through the class tutorial of the official python tutorial but this does not contain what I am looking for.

Comment: Well, the level of your question and your wording suggest that you should be starting the tutorial from the start. You seem to be lacking quite a few basics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that you are looking for the [`append`](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) method of `list`:

```
name = []
name.append(myClass())
name.append(myClass())
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot append items like this to a python list. Do it like

```
name = list()
name.append(myClass())
```

Please be sure to read up on how the basic constructs of python work http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html and http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html